# To build a voice chat mobile apps like talkbox. XMPP / SID or other solutions?

Tags: mobile, xmpp, chat, voice, sid

Good day all, sorry if the question has confused you.

My client has required us to build an IM apps like talkbox.

Thet especially want the voice msg feature in talkbox. i.e. The sender can hold a button to record a short msg. Then receiver can listen to the short msg when click the text msg.

1. What protocol should be used?XMPP/SID?
2. And any other area I should drill into for building an IM app as I am new to this area? Thanks.